# Рисование фигур на C# по массиву точек

Tags: c#, геометрия

Суть вопроса: дан массив точек (x, y), которые гарантированно задают одну из фигур (квадрат, треугольник, окружность). Задача состоит в том, чтобы эту фигуру отрисовать. Знаю про System Drawing, но не понимаю, как  это реализовать.

Comment: а что вы пробовали? Нарисовать линию вроде не очень сложная задача.

Comment: [DrawLines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawlines?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) - метод принимает массив точек и делает именно то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаг 1: получить дескриптор отрисовщика формы/контрола, на котором рисовать, за это отвечает класс Graphics.
Шаг 2: создать кисть, для управления цветом, за это отвечают классы Pen/Brush.
Шаг 3: использовать Graphics для отрисовки, например:
`graphics.DrawLine(pen1, point1, point2)`